# JFrame stops showing content when JFrame.setType is set to Type.POPUP

Tags: java, swing, jframe, window, window-decoration

I have a little JFrame that should not appear in the taskbar and that should be undecorated.
I achieved it with this code, but the Frame is not displaying any content.

```
super();
instance = this;
instance.setUndecorated(true);
instance.setType(JFrame.Type.POPUP);
```

When I replace

`instance.setType(JFrame.Type.POPUP);` with

`instance.setType(JFrame.Type.UTILITY);`

it shows the content again, but also shows the Frame in the taskbar.

Thanks in advance!
Simon

Comment: Did you forget `instance.setVisible(true)` ?

Comment: yes, the frame is visible, but it just doesn't show any content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your frame to be undecorated as well as not visible in desktop you can use [JWindow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JWindow.html).It has all the functionality similar to `JFrame` so replace your `JFrame` with `JWindow`

> A JWindow is a container that can be displayed anywhere on the user's
>   desktop. It does not have the title bar, window-management buttons, or
>   other trimmings associated with a JFrame, but it is still a
>   "first-class citizen" of the user's desktop, and can exist anywhere on
>   it.

Sample JWindow code

```
   JWindow window = new JWindow();
    window.add(new JButton("test"));
    window.setSize(500, 500);
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    window.setVisible(true);
```